# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' --> Python Conversion from PDF to XML

Tags: python, pdfminer

I have a code which should convert a PDF to XML . But When i ran the code , it is showing me error.

**TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

but as am new , i don know what i should do , I tried some of the solution from Browser , but not worked.

Can anyone please help me

```
from io import BytesIO

import pdfminer.converter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def get_xml_py2(file_path):
    in_fp = BytesIO()
    lstRtn = []
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as x:
        in_fp.write(x.read())

    laparams = LAParams(all_texts=True)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(in_fp):
        outfp = BytesIO()
        device = pdfminer.converter.XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=laparams)
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        lstRtn.append(outfp.getvalue())
        device.close()
        outfp.close()

        in_fp.close()

    return lstRtn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = get_xml_py2('Sample.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `BytesIO` in a place that wants `StringIO`.
So import StringIO and change outfp to `outfp=StringIO()`

Also remove `device.close(), outfp.close(), in_fp.close()` from the for loop.

Your resulting code will be

```py
from io import BytesIO, StringIO
import pdfminer.converter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def get_xml_py2(file_path):
    in_fp = BytesIO()
    lstRtn = []
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as x:
        in_fp.write(x.read())

    laparams = LAParams(all_texts=True)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    outfp = StringIO()
    device = pdfminer.converter.XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(in_fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        lstRtn.append(outfp.getvalue())
    device.close()
    outfp.close()
    in_fp.close()
    return lstRtn
```

I removed some assignment from the loop cause i don't think they should be in the it.